# Longest repeating and non-overlapping substring in a huge string

Tags: java, search, substring, out-of-memory, heap-size

I used this program to find the longest repeated substring in a string. I found it on this link(https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-repeating-and-non-overlapping-substring/). This program works perfectly if my input is a smaller string.

```
    static String longestRepeatedSubstring(String str) { 
        int n = str.length(); 
        int LCSRe[][] = new int[n + 1][n + 1]; 

        String res = ""; // To store result  
        int res_length = 0; // To store length of result  

        int i, index = 0; 
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) { 
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= n; j++) { 
                if (str.charAt(i - 1) == str.charAt(j - 1) 
                        && LCSRe[i - 1][j - 1] < (j - i)) { 
                    LCSRe[i][j] = LCSRe[i - 1][j - 1] + 1; 

                    if (LCSRe[i][j] > res_length) { 
                        res_length = LCSRe[i][j]; 
                        index = Math.max(i, index); 
                    } 
                } else { 
                    LCSRe[i][j] = 0; 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        if (res_length > 0) { 
            for (i = index - res_length + 1; i <= index; i++) { 
                res += str.charAt(i - 1); 
            } 
        } 

        return res; 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        String str = "abracadabra"; 
        System.out.println(longestRepeatedSubstring(str)); 
    }
```

However i have a string that has 14553776 characters and when i run the program i always get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. I have tried increasing heap size and this thing with virtual memory.

I wonder if its there any way to solve this problem. Maby improving the program or any other solution?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Thats because this code stores results as new string:

```
String res = ""; // To store result
```

so here:

```
for (i = index - res_length + 1; i <= index; i++) { 
            res += str.charAt(i - 1); 
        }
```

there is a memory leak.
You need to store indexes of result string instead.